# utf-8 and skipinitialspace within a line

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8

I'm recently using pandas to read dataframe from a CSV file. Upon calling the reading the Csv file I also have to include 'utf-8' in order to not get the following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 19: invalid start byte
```

So I go and modify the code like this

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',  'utf-8' )
```

This gets rid of the error, Is there a way to not get this error without including 'utf-8' ?

I have to include *skipinitialspace=True* on my code and I'm note sure how to include it in the line.
The following code gives me an error

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields, 'utf-8')
```

Comment: I never worked with pandas, but according to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) it should be: `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: do you know the encoding of the file though? Is it really `utf-8` ?

Comment: I just used this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177069/how-to-check-encoding-of-a-csv-file) and showed me that I have ANSI

Comment: can you try using the encoding which you found. Also it is better to pass the encoding as @Matthias suggested to avoid [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163846/positional-argument-follows-keyword-argument)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similair problem when working with lots of diferent `txt` files, I developed a small program to parse 50 lines of my file and detect the encoding using chardet.

it's bettter to use more lines as suggested by anky_91 so use 1000 or more.

```
from pathlib import Path
import chardet

files = [f for f in Path(ryour_path).glob('*.csv')] # change ext as you wish

encodings = {}
for file in files

    with open(file,'rb') as f:
        data = f.read(1000) 
    encoding=chardet.detect(data).get("encoding")
    encodings[f'{file}'] = encoding
```

this will give you a dictionary of file paths and encodings you can pass into a `read_csv`

Comment: Nice, chardet performs better with more data. Hence if possible, make it read more lines :)