# SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument [discord.py]

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

This is my code:

```
async def tracklooper(ctx, timesPlayedTrack):
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if (timesPlayedTrack <= totaltime):
        if voice and voice.is_playing():
            voice.stop()
            print(str(timesPlayedTrack))
            run_coroutine_threadsafe(msg.edit(content="Playing "+vTT+" for "+str(timesPlayedTrack)+" time/s"), bot.loop)
            voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audio), after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(tracklooper(ctx, timesPlayedTrack+1)), bot.loop)
            voice.is_playing()
    else:
        run_coroutine_threadsafe(msg.delete(), bot.loop)
        run_coroutine_threadsafe(ctx.send("Finished playing "+vTT+" for "+str(totaltime)+" times"), bot.loop)
        run_coroutine_threadsafe(looptrack_set_times.delete(), bot.loop)
        run_coroutine_threadsafe(ply.delete(), bot.loop)
```

This is the error:

```
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audio), after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(tracklooper(ctx, timesPlayedTrack+1)), bot.loop)
                                                                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

I am not very familiar with python language so I am having trouble finding the fix.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [positional argument follows keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163846/positional-argument-follows-keyword-argument)

Answer (score 0):

Keyword arguments, in your case `after=lambda...`, should always be placed at the end of the function call. You have put `bot.loop` at the end, which is *not* a keyword argument.

Looking at the API docs, the only parameters of `VoiceClient.play` are the `source` and `after`, so you should just remove `bot.loop`, as you have already provided both parameters.